# Carousel indicators are not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have the following issue , I can't click when trying to click on the indicators they don't change like if the code does not taking any effects.

```css
    .blog .carousel-indicators li {
        background: #708198;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
      }
      
      .blog .carousel-indicators .active {
        background: #0fc9af;
      }
      
      
      
      
      .item-carousel-blog-block {
        outline: medium none;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog {
        border: 1px solid #dadada;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 4;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-image {
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-image figure img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-date {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        padding: 4px 20px;
        top: -20px;
        right: 8px;
        background-color: #41cb52;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-date span {
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.2;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-date span.mon {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-date span.day {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-body {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .item-heading-blog a h5 {
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        text-decoration:none;
        transition: color 0.3s;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-heading a {
          text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-data p {
        font-size: 13px;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-data p i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      
      .item-box-blog-text {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      
      .mt-10 {
        float: left;
        margin-top: -10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      
      .btn.bg-blue-ui.white.read {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 4px 20px;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      
      .btn.bg-blue-ui.white.read:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px inset #4d5f77;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container cta-100 ">

                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row blog">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <div id="blogCarousel" class="carousel slide container-blog" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                          <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                          <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        </ol>
                                                                         <center><h4 class="title text-uppercase fw-normal mb-4">Latest <span class="text-primary fw-bold">News</span> </h4></center>

                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-4" >
                                <div class="item-box-blog">
                                  <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                                    <!--Date-->
                                    <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                                    <!--Image-->
                                    <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                                    <!--Heading-->
                                    <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                                      <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                                        <h5>News Title</h5>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Data-->
                                    <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                                      <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Text-->
                                    <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                                    <!--Read More Button-->
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
```

when I click on the little circles nothing happen.. like if the code does not take any effects, its made with bootstrap for the big part of it
[image]

Comment: Where is the JavaScript with event handlers and such?

Comment: @TJ, there were not, I took it from here : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/BxA1B

Comment: maybe you're missing the scripts initializing the carousel? Have you included these?

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` - must appear before the slider html in the source code, best put into in the `<head>` element.

Comment: the thing is that i've included them but in the end the website was very slow and even once loaded it was not working, knowing that in the header I have already something like "  
   
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />          
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tiny-slider.css"/> 
        <link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        "

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery and Bootstrap's JS which is present in `bootsnipp.com/snippets/BxA1B`:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.blog .carousel-indicators li {
  background: #708198;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.blog .carousel-indicators .active {
  background: #0fc9af;
}

.item-carousel-blog-block {
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item-box-blog {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 4;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-box-blog-image {
  position: relative;
}

.item-box-blog-image figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item-box-blog-date {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  top: -20px;
  right: 8px;
  background-color: #41cb52;
}

.item-box-blog-date span {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.item-box-blog-date span.mon {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item-box-blog-date span.day {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.item-box-blog-body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-heading-blog a h5 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.item-box-blog-heading a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item-box-blog-data p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.item-box-blog-data p i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.item-box-blog-text {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mt-10 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn.bg-blue-ui.white.read {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn.bg-blue-ui.white.read:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px inset #4d5f77;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container cta-100 ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row blog">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="blogCarousel" class="carousel slide container-blog" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#blogCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Carousel items -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="item-box-blog">
                    <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                      <!--Date-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                      <!--Image-->
                      <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                      <!--Heading-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                          <h5>News Title</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--Data-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                      </div>
                      <!--Text-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem
                          ipsum dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                      <!--Read More Button-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="item-box-blog">
                    <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                      <!--Date-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                      <!--Image-->
                      <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                      <!--Heading-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                          <h5>News Title</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--Data-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                      </div>
                      <!--Text-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem
                          ipsum dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                      <!--Read More Button-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="item-box-blog">
                    <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                      <!--Date-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                      <!--Image-->
                      <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                      <!--Heading-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                          <h5>News Title</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--Data-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                      </div>
                      <!--Text-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem
                          ipsum dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                      <!--Read More Button-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--.row-->
            </div>
            <!--.item-->
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="item-box-blog">
                    <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                      <!--Date-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                      <!--Image-->
                      <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                      <!--Heading-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                          <h5>News Title</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--Data-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                      </div>
                      <!--Text-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem
                          ipsum dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                      <!--Read More Button-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="item-box-blog">
                    <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                      <!--Date-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                      <!--Image-->
                      <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                      <!--Heading-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                          <h5>News Title</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--Data-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                      </div>
                      <!--Text-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem
                          ipsum dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                      <!--Read More Button-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="item-box-blog">
                    <div class="item-box-blog-image">
                      <!--Date-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-date bg-blue-ui white"> <span class="mon">Augu 01</span> </div>
                      <!--Image-->
                      <figure> <img alt="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/14/25/computer-2048983_960_720.jpg"> </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-box-blog-body">
                      <!--Heading-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-heading">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="0">
                          <h5>News Title</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--Data-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-data" style="padding: px 15px;">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Admin, <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comments(3)</p>
                      </div>
                      <!--Text-->
                      <div class="item-box-blog-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Lorem
                          ipsum dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt"> <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn bg-blue-ui white read">read more</a> </div>
                      <!--Read More Button-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--.row-->
            </div>
            <!--.item-->
          </div>
          <!--.carousel-inner-->
        </div>
        <!--.Carousel-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery, therefore i think jQuery must be included first.

Comment: Ah yes, it's in proper order in my snippet, above is copy pasta from bootsnip: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/BxA1B, it somehow works though.

Comment: "copy pasta" - XD